# iPod detail view icon

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uinavigationitem

So I'm having the hardest time figuring out what this thing is called, or where I can find it. I have an app where I would like to use this icon, or button or whatever it is, but I can't find it in Apple's system supplied buttons.

Here is a picture of the icon I'm looking for (it's in the red circle):

[image]

I know that Pandora uses this same icon, but where the heck did they find it?

Thanks,
Robbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That button is a custom image, it's not part of the standard icons that come with the SDK. I'd guess Pandora recreated the image.